# Sql Server 2008: Alternative for inefficient subquery in select clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have a table:

SourceID, TargetID, Amount, Year.

I also have a view. This view is looking at differences between a row and the row above it in the same table. I use CTE to do this:

```
    WITH cte as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY SourceID ORDER BY ... ) as rowNum, 
SourceId, TargetID, Amount, Year FROM table)

    Select 
    t1.SourceID as SourceID1, 
t2.SourceID as SourceID2, 
t1.TargetID as TargetID1, 
t2.TargetID as TargetID2, 
t1.Year, 
(t1.Amount - t2.Amount) as Difference

    FROM cte t1
    LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.SourceID = t2.SourceID and t1.rowNum = t2.rowNum+1
```

I now have 2 columns in that view. TargetID1 and TargetID2. TargetID2 is the same as TargetID1 in the row above. Sometimes TargetID2 is null, because the conditions were not met in the left join displayed above. That is fine. Selecting * from this view is exactly what I need.

The problem here is when I want to select conditionally. For example: I only want to select rows that have 2012 as year. Ofcourse technically this is not a problem, but when the first row in 2012 is comparing itself to the (now invisible) last row of 2011 the customer gets confused. They want Difference to be empty (NULL) when its the first row in the resultset meeting the join conditions.

So I wrote this:

```
SELECT
    SourceID1, SourceID2, TargetID1, TargetID2, Year,
    case when TargetID2 is null
    then null
    else case when TargetID2 NOT IN (
        select TargetID1 from view where Year = 2012)
    then null
    else Difference
    end
    end as Difference,
FROM view where Year = 2012
```

This actually worked... It took a little longer because its a fairly large table, but it was acceptable. Now we are adding a percentage (the difference in percentage). This means that this last query is expanded with another conditional select checking the exact same contion.

```
case when TargetID2 is null
   then null
   else case when TargetID2 NOT IN (
    select TargetID1 from view where Year = 2012)
   then null
   else Percentage
   end
   end as Percentage
```

So this is getting very consuming.

My question is: what should I do? Changes to the solution in general, to the view or to the query are all fine. There are no limitations whatsoever as long as the filtered result shows the first row with a null as difference and percentage and the query performs.

Sorry for the large post. Didn't know how else to put this.

Thanks

EDIT:

I was not clear enough on problem. If Year would be the only concern I could do some of the suggestions below, but its not. I simplified the table and view so it would be more readable, but there are other columns and other things one can filter on.

There is also a month column. So if I want to see october 2011 - februari 2012 then the last row of 2011 should be compared to the first row of 2012. Here the first row of october should have the NULL Difference and Percentage columns because its TargetID2 does not exist in the TargetID1 column...

I hope that clears it up. Maybe I should start from scratch with this question.

Comment: I read through this and missed what feedback you were looking for, other than it was consuming.  Does it work?  Is it fast enough?  Use of ISNULL() and NULLIF() would help readability instead of using the case statements.

Comment: I do not understand why are you using subquery - you already select year in cte and you can use it to discover if `t2.Year` does not equal `t1.Year`. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you do filtering in `CTE` resulting t2 rows will be null for `rowNum = 1`. If you do it later you have to add the same filters to `left join` to nullify non-matching rows. I'd go with filters in `CTE`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that null rows will help mathematic because any operation will result in null, which is exactly what you customers want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems harder to explain than I thought. I decided to go with my previous solution, but put everything in a Stored Procedure instead of a view + query. This way it wont have to iterate over the same table so many times. Thanks for the support everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you never want to compare a row of one year to a row of the previous year. If that is the case you should add `AND t1.Year = t2.Year` to the join condition in the view.

If this is incorrect and somehow 2012 is a special year you could add the `t2.Year` column to the view. That way you could use it directly and would not have to join to rediscover it.

Comment: No. I'm not comparing years, I'm comparing rows. There can be multiple rows in the same year where each row compares (itself) to the row above. Say row 20 is in 2011 and row 21 is in 2012, row 21 should have NULL in column difference when only selecting 2012 because in that case row 20 is not provided and the difference for 21 should not be calculated.

Comment: That is exactly what that additional condition for the JOIN would provide.